# Calling an aliased-declared base class constructor in a different namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, base-class, using-declaration

I am trying to understand some details of alias-declared classes through C++11's `using` and how/why this affects a base class constructor call.

### Example Code

```
#include <iostream>

namespace N {

  template<typename T>
  struct Foo
  {
//     Foo(){}; // NOTE: If this line is present, error 2 goes away.
    Foo(T t):value(t){};
    ~Foo() = default;
    T value; 
  };

  struct BarInt : public Foo<int>
  {
    BarInt(int t):Foo< int >(t){};
    ~BarInt() = default;
  };

  using BarFloat = Foo<float>;

};

struct A : public N::BarInt
{
  A(int i=42):BarInt(i){}; //BarInt(i) or N::BarInt(i) doesn't matter here
  ~A() = default;
};

struct B : public N::BarFloat
{
  B(float f=23.0):BarFloat(f){}; //two errors with gcc4.7.2 (with -std=gnu++11)

//   B(float f=23.1):N::BarFloat(f){}; //this line seems to work.
  ~B() = default;
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  A a;
  B b;  
  std::cout << "a's value is "<< a.value << "\n"
            << "b's value is "<< b.value << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

gcc 4.7.2 (compiling with -std=gnu++11) generates two errors for this code which I believe to be related (although I do not understand how...)

### Error 1

```
main.cpp: In constructor ‘B::B(float)’:
main.cpp:32:19: error: class ‘B’ does not have any field named ‘BarFloat’
```

My searches on stackoverflow brought up [Is a namespace required when referring to the base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277477/c-is-a-namespace-required-when-referring-to-the-base-class), which mentions *injected class name* as a starting point for a further search. However, from what I gathered, this explains why I can write the constructor for `A` the way I did it (i.e. as `A(int i=42):BarInt(i){};`) and why `BarInt(i)` does not have to be qualified with the namespace `N`.

So why doesn't that work with `B`? According to  [What is the difference between 'typedef' and 'using' in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11), `using` is the same as a good old `typedef`, so I guess my question for the first error is how alias-declared class (`BarFloat` in my example) differ from regular classes (`BarInt` in my example) in the context of injecting class names. Any pointers are greatly appreciated :)

### Error 2

```
main.cpp:32:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘N::Foo<double>::Foo()’
main.cpp:32:29: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:9:5: note: N::Foo<T>::Foo(T) [with T = double]
main.cpp:9:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:6:10: note: constexpr N::Foo<double>::Foo(const N::Foo<double>&)
main.cpp:6:10: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

This error goes away if I, as already noted in the example code above, introduce an empty `Foo()` constructor. The question I have, however, is why `BarFloat(f)` triggers a call to the empty `Foo()` constructor and, in that case, how `BarFloat.value` would be possibly set to 23.0.

#### Post Scriptum

As this is my first post here: Hello stackoverflow and thank you all for the tremendous help you already provided to me through helping others with their problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inherit from a class, the derived class can access the names of the base class (including the base class name itself) without qualification.  You are effectively inheriting the names in the base class.  This is why inheriting from `N::BarInt` allows you to refer to `BarInt` within `A` without qualification.

For `B`, you are inheriting from `Foo<double>` using the BarFloat alias, but `Foo<double>` doesn't contain `BarFloat`, so you don't inherit that name.

The second error is just because of the first failure.  Since the compiler didn't see a valid initialization of the base, it is just like you didn't explicitly ininitialize the base at all, so it is forced to initialize it with the default constructor, which you don't have.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, although I do have some follow up questions: for error 1, you effectively explain why it works for `BarInt`, but do you have an idea why it doesn't work for `BarFloat`? And for error 2, the missing empty constructor: if the compiler doesn't find the base (`BarFloat`) due to the missing namespace, how does it know about the base of the base, i.e. `Foo`?

Comment: @hcc23: The second paragraph describes why it doesn't work for BarFloat.  I may have added that after you first saw my answer though.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that second paragraph (which I must have missed while typing my first comment), that seems to make sense to me.

Comment: @hcc23: The compiler processes the text largely from top to bottom.  When you declare `B`, you are specifying that it has a base of `N::BarFloat`, and that works fine, since it is qualified.  At that point, the rest of the class can now see the contents of `Foo<double>`.  The compiler just can't see `BarFloat` because it isn't within `Foo<double>`.