# How does c++ decide which namespace to pick if it is omited

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer

Why was the last A [picked](https://postimg.cc/1gQYg63W) from ns1 namespace instead of ns2?
(Bar is of [type](https://postimg.cc/dhKzCgWm)
`ns1::A<ns1::A<ns2::A, ns2::B>, ns2::B>`)

```
namespace ns1 {
  template <typename T, typename U>
  struct A {};
}

namespace ns2 {
  struct /*ns2*/ A : ns1::A<int, /*ns2*/ A> {
    typedef ns1::A<int, /*ns2*/ A> Foo;
  };
  struct B : ns1::A< /*ns2*/ A, B> {
    typedef ns1::A< /*ns1*/ A, B> Bar;
  };
}
```

I'm using vscode with g++ 11.2.0

Comment: @JasonLiam from [IDE](https://postimg.cc/1gQYg63W) and from compilation bugs

Comment: @JasonLiam it is not a [type](https://postimg.cc/dhKzCgWm) of Bar, it is type of A

Comment: If the namespace is omited [sic], the compiler will search the global namespace.  If there are more namespaces with the `using` statement, those will be searched also.

Comment: You're right, [here](https://godbolt.org/z/dcTdzjoME) is an example that prints the type of `Bar` without relying on an IDE - it prints `ns1::A<ns1::A<ns2::A, ns2::B>, ns2::B>` with both GCC and clang.

Comment: The reason is that the `A` refers to the base class of `ns2::B` (it's allowed not to specify the template arguments when referring to the base class).

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277477/is-a-namespace-required-when-referring-to-the-base-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ classes have an *injected class name* available in class scope, which refers to the class itself. For example, for `ns1::A<T, U>`, the name `A` refers to `ns1::A<T, U>` in class scope .

This injected class name can also be accessed in derived classes, so in `ns2::B`, the name `A` refers to the base class which is `ns1::A<ns2::A, ns2::B>`.

The injected class name behaves like a member typedef, so it takes precedence over namespace-scope names when in class scope. To refer to a namespace-scope type you'd need to qualify it.

Within `ns2::A`, you get different behavior: here the base class has an injected class name `A` referring to `ns1::A<int, ns2::A>` (similarly to before), but `ns2::A` also has an injected class name `A` referring to itself. The derived class's names take precedence so `A` refers to `ns2::A` here.

Answer (score 0):

From [unqualified names](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup):

> For a name used anywhere in class definition (including base class specifiers and nested class definitions), except inside a member function body, a default argument of a member function, exception specification of a member function, or default member initializer, where the member may belong to a nested class whose definition is in the body of the enclosing class, **the following scopes are searched**:
>
> - the **body of the class in which the name is used** until the point of use

(emphasis mine)

Now let us apply this to the two cases.

##### Case 1

Here we consider:

```
namespace ns2 {
//-------------------v---------->#1  
  struct B : ns1::A< A, B> {
//------------------v----------->#2
    typedef ns1::A< A, B> Bar;
  };
}
```

In this case, the **unqualified name** `A` at point `#1` is looked up and according to bullet point 1 quoted above, it refers to `ns2::A`.

Now, the base class of `B` is `ns1::A<  ns2::A, ns2::B>` and this base class has an injected-class name `A` which refers to the **current instantiation** `ns1::A<  ns2::A, ns2::B>`. Moreover, it is as-if this base class has a public member named `A` referring to `ns1::A<  ns2::A, ns2::B>`.

This means that the derived class `B` behaves as-if it has an inherited member named `A` from the base class.

Now, the `A` at point `#2` is looked up and since this derived class `B` has inherited a member named `A`(same as `ns1::A`) from the base class, the bullet point 1 founds this `ns1::A`(which itself refers to `ns1::A<  ns2::A, ns2::B>`). This also explains why in your posted image the type of `A` at point `#2` is `ns1::A<  ns2::A, ns2::B>`.

##### Case 2

Here we consider:

```
namespace ns2 {
//-------------------------------v------> #1
  struct /*ns2*/ A : ns1::A<int, A> {
//----------------------v---------------> #2
    typedef ns1::A<int, A> Foo;
  };
 
}
```

At point `#1`, according to bullet point 1, `A` is refers to `ns2::A` just like in case 1 discussed before.

But this time the inherited member named `A` from base class `ns1::A<int, ns2::A>` is **hidden** by a member with the same name. This is because the class `ns2::A` itself has an injected-class name `A` so it is as-if it has a member named `A` which will hide the inherited member with the same name from the base.

This in turn means that the `A` at point `#2` refers to `ns2::A`(unlike in case 1).